# Graphql - get data from multiple sources

Tags: graphql, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

With the Graphql, how can we get the data from the different sources. Here is my table/model

```
Employee{
 name,
 deptId
}
```

I require the department details, such as the department name, when I query an employee. However, the department is in another microservice that is exposed via restservice. How can we achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. A GraphQL request tells your server what data it wants back based on what fields you say are available. How you get that data is something that the request won't care about, so if you need to make 50 other REST calls, while it would be slow, you're free to do so and aggregate the data as necessary